# How to generate netflow data in linux

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, linux-networking, netflow

We have a number of Linux servers for which I would like to capture netflow data to be processed by a netflow analyzer. I've been spoiled by the ease in which Mikrotik routers allow netflow data generation, but I haven't managed to find an **opensource** tool that is able to generate netflow data for multiple interfaces on a Linux system.

I have come across **[fprobe](http://fprobe.sourceforge.net/)** but it seems quite buggy. Admittedly I haven't spent much time with it yet since I'd also like to evaluate some other possibilities. The other tool I've seen mentioned is **[nprobe](http://www.ntop.org/nProbe.html)**, which appears to be GPL, but is not available as a free download since it is only offered for a fee.

The servers on which I plan to generate netflow data are all Gentoo systems, but this shouldn't really make any difference. At most it means I would have to manually compile a tool from source.

**Summary:** I'm looking for an opensource netflow generator that will work on Linux and allows capturing flows for multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should check [IPT-NETFLOW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipt-netflow/), it seems exactly what you need implemented as a kernel module for IPTABLES. It is actively maintained and [used succesfully in some ISP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipt-netflow/reviews/) so should be good enough. Documentation could be better though (look into README file).

Comment: I don't like the idea of having to compile custom kernel modules - that can affect stability, unless indeed it's a very well tested and stable module...

Comment: This isn't freebsd where such software can be developed against already in place kernel features like netgraph. Hardly any way to do this without a custom module. The good thing (and that's why i'm commenting) is that the sources are now on github and it also has dkms support now. Looks pretty good. https://github.com/aabc/ipt-netflow

Answer (score 9):

[ntop](http://www.ntop.org/netflow.html) will do it, but is probably not the best choice. Definitely check out [pmacct](http://www.pmacct.net/); it's designed exactly for this. From the feature list:

- Collects data through libpcap, Netlink/ULOG, NetFlow v1/v5/v7/v8/ - v9, sFlow v2/v4/v5 and IPFIX
- Saves data to a number of backendsincluding memory tables, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and BerkeleyDB
- Exports data to remote collectors through IPFIX, NetFlow v5/v9 andsFlow v5
- Replicates incoming IPFIX, NetFlow and sFlow packets to remote collectors

Among many other things.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a newer project for collecting and analyzing NetFlow data on Linux: [ElastiFlow](https://github.com/robcowart/elastiflow)

Answer (score 0):

the advantage of [fprobe](http://fprobe.sourceforge.net/) is that it can generate Netflow streams using regular [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [ulogd](http://netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/).

it is a little more dated, and seems indeed buggier, but it may be useful to bootstrap a setup, as it does not require compiling a kernel module (like [ipt-netflow](https://github.com/aabc/ipt-netflow)) and doesn't ship any additional features (like [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/netflow.html) or [pmacct](http://www.pmacct.net/)).